# OCI8 not showing in phpinfo for wampp

Tags: oracle, php

I have installed wampp server and oracle client on my server.
But when I enable oci8 from php extension.
The phpinfo not showing OCI8 and I am unable to connect oracle through php.

My php ini show dll are active..
Can any on help??

Answer (score 0):

First I suggest you to make sure that both php.ini files in following locations `wamp\bin\php\php5.4.3\php.ini` and `wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.2\bin\php.ini` shows that dll is enabled.

if these are enabled and you are still facing the same issue than it may possible that your pcp_oci8.dll is corrupt, I suggest download new dll as per the php version and replace older dll. you can find these dll's in `wamp\bin\php\php5.4.3\ext`. once you replace this than restart your wamp server.